# ng-class doesn't update when it should after function invoked with ng-click is executed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a problem with ng-class in AngularJS - it doesn't update properly.

**View:**

```
<div class="cal-day" ng-repeat="day in schedule">
    ...
    <div class="entry" ng-click="entryDetails(entry)" ng-repeat="entry in day.blockGrid"
     ng-class="{'selected': isSelected(entry), 'bg-{{entry.color}}': entry, 'bg-empty': !entry}">
         {{isSelected(entry)}}
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.entryDetails = function(entry) {
    $scope.entryForDetails = entry;
};

$scope.isSelected = function(entry) {
    return $scope.entryForDetails === entry;
};
```

CSS class *selected* is implemented fine - when I replace *isSelected(entry)* with *true* in *ng-class*, the class gets applied properly.
Same thing with *isSelected()* function - it correctly prints *true* or *false* depending on whether the item is selected.
Even though both elements work, they somehow refuse to work together, and the div class doesn't get updated to *selected* when *isSelected(entry)* returns *true*.

Edit:

**Model stored in *day***

```
  {
    "date": "6.6.2013",
    "blockGrid": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        "group": "ABCD",
        "subjectName": "AB CD",
        "subjectShorthand": "PW",
        "type": "c",
        "number": 4,
        "profName": "ABAB",
        "date": "2013-06-05T22:00:00.000Z",
        "venue": "329 S",
        "timetableBlock": 7,
        "color": 16,
        "_id": "51c3a442eb2e46a7220000e2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see, it's an array of 7 elements which are either null or contain an *entry* object.

I forgot to mention that posted section of my view is inside another ng-repeat. View code snippet above is now expanded to reflect that.

Comment: Can you post the model stored in `day.blockGrid`?

Comment: I thought ng-class evaluated to a boolean.. yet here it is evaluating `null` and `!null`.  Is this allowed?

Comment: That has to be the issue. Eliminate everything in `ng-class` except for the first expression, and it works:  [Plunker here](http://plunker.co/edit/oK8A8isw9tmTerJ9zUtn?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Ng-class, as you have set it up, is wanting to evaluate a boolean expression, which your first expression in the object has done.  However, the next two expressions are trying to evaluate the `entry` object, and not the result of `isSelected(entry)`, which returns true/false.

So to correct:

```
ng-class="{'selected': isSelected(entry), 'bg':isSelected(entry), 'bg-empty':!isSelected(entry)}"
```

That is, unless you are trying something else.  Also notice that I removed `bg-{{entry.color}}`.  I have no clue how to evaluate a scope property within an ng-class, or if it is even possible.

[Here is the working plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oK8A8isw9tmTerJ9zUtn?p=preview).  This may not be what you are after, but it can at least help you troubleshoot.